# Dicussion Board alerts on lists when deleted?

Tags: alert, information-management, expiration

I'm recieving alerts from the list that has the expiration policy on it. Not sure if that has anything to do with why it's sending out alerts...

> From: Site Collection server@domain.com 
>   To: user@domain.com 
>   Subject: Discussion Board - Discussion Board Discussions 
>   Reply-To: Administrators@domain.com 
>   Site Collection Sub Site
>   Discussion Board Discussions has been deleted 
>     Modify my alert settings |  View Discussion Board
>
> Last Modified DATE by System Account

I've checked SharePoint Manager and they seem legit. They do run whenever the expiration policy is scheduled to run. Why is the expiration policy job triggering alerts (if that's the cause)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are the alert settings for the list?  Do users get notified if the item changes or deleted?

I believe that expiration, once reached, will edit the properties of the item, and thus trigger an alert.  If the expiration deletes the item and the alert is set to notify on deletion, then the alert would trigger also.

Comment: Most of the users have the alerts set to all changes, which included deletion, but this did not happen for MOSS 2007 expiration policies.

Comment: How can I stop the retention policy to stop sending out alerts?

Comment: The retention policy isn't sending out the alerts, it's just doing it's job of cleaning things up.  It's the alerts doing it.  Try adjusting the alert configuration to trigger on different settings, not where anything changes.

Comment: Is there a way to change mass alerts to trigger changes and additions but not deletions?